# Convert string into a executable command

Tags: php, parsing

So let's say I have variable like this one:

```
$q = "DB::select('id')->from('reports')->where('field', '=', 'value');";
```

Now how can I remove `" "` or do something that would make it executable query?

```
$q = DB::select('id')->from('reports')->where('field', '=', 'value');
```

Btw I'm using the kohana framework, but I don't think that it matters since it's a simple php code.

Comment: You can use [`eval`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) but I'd find a better way to build a query over parsing a string as code first.

Comment: The basic rule of thumb: If you need to use `eval()`, you're doing something **very wrong**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by using [`eval`](https://www.php.net/eval). Eval is considered very harmful, so make sure you sanitize everything before even considering to use `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = "DB::select('id')->from('reports')->where('field', '=', 'value');";
eval('$q = ' . $q);
```

Source: http://php.net/eval

PS: avoid using eval when you're not 100% certain about the content that will be eval'ed. There must be a reason the levenshtein between eval & evil is only 1!

Answer (score 1):

Use the eval() function.

```
eval("$q = " . "DB::select('id')->from('reports')->where('field', '=', 'value');");
```

Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the eval() function: -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php